# Why does yandex return 405, when google return 200 Ok?

Tags: indexing, seo

I have following problem with site http://huti.ru. When trying to add any of its pages in http://webmaster.yandex.ru/addurl.xml (Yandex - russian search engine) wrote "The server returns a status code http 405 (expected code 200)." What can caouse such different behevior for brawusers and yandex crawler? (Google indexes like normal)

Enviroment: tomcat, java 6

Comment: 405 means `method not allowed`. Sounds strange. You'll have to look at your server logs to see what goes wrong and at which point. This is more of a sysadmin issue, maybe better suited on serverfault.com, I'm not sure

Comment: Also, as far as Google Translate tells me, this page may be interesting for you: http://help.yandex.ru/webmaster/?id=995305

Comment: Since this isn't a programming question, it belongs on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your server does not allow HEAD requests. Seems that the robot first tries a HEAD before the actual GET.

As 
http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html
states: HEAD should be identical to GET, except that it does never return a message body, but only the response headers for a particular request.

Note: I did a simple

```
HEAD / HTTP/1.0
```

request. Same with `HTTP/1.1` + `Host: huti.ru`.

Comment: I got 200 on a handcrafted `HEAD` request issued through Fiddler. I wonder if the particular problem is not related to one of the other headers.

Comment: Yes you are right the problem was with HEAD request it havent been supported.

Answer (score 1):

Check your server logs for the actual content of the response to the Yandex request.

[HTTP 405](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_405#4xx_Client_Error) is Method Not Allowed, and is usually returned if the user agent has used an HTTP verb not supported for the particular resource.

For example, using [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com), I issued several requests to http://huti.ru, and I got 200 response for the `HEAD`, `GET`, and `POST`, but I got 405 for the `TRACE`. It's conceivable that Yandex issues either `TRACE` or `OPTIONS`, before making a request for the actual page as a form of a ping to determine if the page exists.

Note: @smilingthax mentioned that your server returns 405 on `HEAD`. However, issuing the following request from Fiddler worked for me:

```
HEAD http://huti.ru/ HTTP/1.1
Host: huti.ru
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
Accept: application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/8.0.552.23 Safari/534.10
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
```

Thus, your problem might be specific to `HEAD` requests with particular headers.

Answer (score 0):

I think that 405 means that the page has already been indexed.

Comment: No it is not. Even some checkers return 200 like http://www.webconfs.com/http-header-check.php. and some return 504 like http://www.bertal.ru/index.php